# Insert and fill a non restricted field with the new unique key autoincrement id value

Tags: mysql

I have a table with two fields:

- Unique Id autoincrement -> Id
- int -> copyOfId

Id can be written manually, or can be assigned by database but copyOfId.
To set the same value to Id and copyOfId, I can do this:

```
set @nextId = (select id from table order by id desc limit 1) + 1;
insert into table (Id,...,...,...,copyOfId,...,...,...
) VALUES (
@nextId,...,...,...,@nextId,...,...,...);
```

Is it possible to set the copyOfId with the same Id on an Insert automatically?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to set the copyOfId with the same Id on an Insert automatically?

No. Neither BEFORE trigger nor generated column may refer to autoincremented column.

But you may remove autoincrementing, create separate table with autoincremented column, and set both id and its copy from BEFORE trigger.

<kbd>[**Example fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=024eabdb5520b0f7ae3418a8aaa865e8)</kbd> with some explanations.

Pay attention - the values for `id` and its copy provided in INSERT will be overwritten unconditionally. If you need to set them manually to some `N` then insert a row with `N-1` value (which must be above current maximal value) into additional table explicitly then insert into working table.

Do not update PK value in working table with the value above current maximal value.